# Matlab code that outputs several matrices

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a Matlab code that, given a matrix, outputs 3 matrices (according to some rules). I'm having difficulty getting this to work though - I can't output a vector with matrices as entries. I get the error message:

> ???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I
>   must be the same.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: please show us (the relevant portion of) the code you've already got

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write

```
function [A B C] = myFunction(X)
    A = X;
    B = 2 * X;
    C = 3 * X;
end
```

and call it with

```
[a b c] = myFunction(ones(2))
```

If you won't want all of the outputs, just call it with

```
a = myFunction(ones(2))
```

or

```
[a b] = myFunction(ones(2))
```

to get just the first argument, or just the first two arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to adapt this so that the number of matrices output can be anything up to 3?

Comment: Thanks. I realise I should have been more specific: sometimes myFunction will output 1 matrix, sometimes 2 and sometimes 3 (dependent on the input matrix). I want to call myFunction inside another function I am writing, and then use the matrices outputted by MyFunction. I don't 'know' in advance how many arguments myFunction is going to give me. How can I get round this?

Comment: I think I've managed to make it work, by setting 'empty' outputs to 0. In other words, if MyFunction(X) should only need to record 2 matrices (say A and C), I set B = 0. In my other function (which calls MyFunction), I can then use 
T = [A B C];

index = find(T);

T = T(index); to remove the 0.

Comment: I can't help but feel that you're overcomplicating it. If you could edit your question to include the problem you're actually trying to solve (rather than what you *think* you need to do to solve this problem) then I will probably be able to be much more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cells:

```
A=cell(1,3); %% or A=cell(1,2); if you want to output only 2 matrices
A{1}=B;
A{2}=C;
A{3}=D;
```

If your matrices all have the same size you can also concatenate them:

```
A=zeros(m,n,3);
A(:,:,1)=B;
A(:,:,2)=C;
A(:,:,3)=D;
```

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration:

```
 function [A, B, C] = something (Input_mat)
 %Do whatever needs to be done here, for example:
 A= Input_mat;
 B= Input_mat';
 C= ones(18);
```

And then when you call it using:

```
 [A,B,C] = something (Some_mat)
```

A, B and C are filled.